# Why the page is reloaded if you don't use Ajax in JavaScript app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, asynchronous, fetch

I'm a Java developer and I'm learning frontend with JavaScript and React. And now I'm learning about Ajax. And I see that this Ajax is used to fetch data asynchronous from an API without refreshing the web page. But I don't understand this statement. So, if I fetch data without Ajax the page is reloaded? Is there an example to see this practically? I mean, to fetch data from an API without Ajax and the page is reloaded. In my opinion if you fetch data from an API synchronous, it will wait to receive the data, and during this time the flow will be stopped, and when the data is fetched, the flow will continue. But why the page is reloaded?

I used this implementation in a simple React app:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    //     .then(response => response.json())
    //     .then(users => this.setState({ users: users }));

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', true);

    request.onload = () => {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            this.setState({ users: data });
        } else {

        }
    }

    request.send();
}
```

So, I understand that if I change the flag from true to false, the request will be changed from asynchronous to synchronous, and the request will be done without Ajax.

But I don't see any difference in the app if I make the request with the flag true or false.

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Ajax is used to fetch data asynchronous from an API without refreshing the web page. But I don't understand this statement.

That statement is relevant to browser JavaScript where a `form submit()` is necessary to fetch new informations.
The AJAX combinaison of technologies then allowed to update a single part of an already loaded page without using the browser's "submit".

Now with React... You are using a more recent technology where every component can be re-rendered individually based on state change.
So the concept of a web page as a whole that would reload as a whole is quite the opposite of the React concept.

The `async` flag should be always be true (its default value) with React as you do not want to "freeze" any JS execution.